# use grpc reflection service to build static model

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc, buf

I am building a client to a specific grpc application, that exposes also the reflection service (so, for example, I can use `grpc_cli` to check the exposed call/types).

ATM I *don*'t have direct access to the `.proto` files that have been used to build the service.
I could ask for a copy of them, or to share the `.proto` files in a dedicated shared space, but I'm wondering if it's possible to instrument `protoc` (or `buf`) to generate the source code of the model for my application fetching the informations directly from the reflection service.

Or at least some way to generate the `.proto` files (or the descriptor...) locally (then it's just a two-step solution)

Is it possible? How?

(If that could help, the server has been written in `typescript` and my client is in `java`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reflection API uses descriptors, and [grpcurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) can export them as a `google.protobuf.FileDescriptorSet`. Both protoc and the [buf CLI](https://github.com/bufbuild/buf) can use the binary descriptors to generate code.

Here is an example:

```bash
grpcurl -protoset-out eliza-descriptors.bin demo.connectrpc.com:443 describe
```

The command retrieves descriptors via reflection from a demo service (source at https://github.com/connectrpc/examples-go), and writes them to a file.

The following command generates code from the descriptors.

```bash
buf generate eliza-descriptors.bin
```

Comments in proto files won't make it, but besides that, the result is identical to what you would get if you had the original proto sources.

Comment: thanks for bringing up `grpcurl` (and the `-protoset-out` option))